# HTML leading slash on all src's and href's

Tags: html

I have a quite large website to work with and all its HREF's, SRC's and paths have a leading slash like this src="/main-folder/....
On the server where the site runs now everything works fine, but whenever it's moved it doesn't, for instance if moved to example.com/test-folder/main-folder this happens:

in example.com/test-folder/index.html a link to about.html will redirect to:

example.com/main-folder/about.html where in fact it is in:

example.com/test-folder/main-folder/about.html

simply removing the leading slash solves the issue, but there are tons of links and image sources, and the site is HTML based and using PHP will require changing all files (to use things like "**__*FILE*__**" )
any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like you could find a regex that would make short work of the issue.

Comment: Note that removing the leading slash may have undesired effects if you are linking from anything other than the top level of your website. I.e. If your website has a page test-folder/sub-folder/child-folder/index.html and it contains a link to the CSS file /css/sitestyles.css then removing the leading slash would leave the resulting path test-folder/sub-folder/child-folder/css/sitestyles.css - this would also be incorrect. You probably want to use relative paths such as ../../css/sitestyles.css - this may be difficult to automate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you do a find for

```
href="/
```

and replace with

```
href="
```

?  Seems like it will take care of all of them at once.

Comment: Some hrefs are "../ others don't need to be replaced, but thanks for the answer and find and replace is the only way with regular expressions